# Mootools class - storing reference to document body in a class property

Tags: javascript, mootools, javascript-framework

Greetings all! I'm trying to learn Mootools classes. I've made this class to add a div to the page.

```
var F = new Class({

    Implements: [Options, Events],

    options: {
        container: document.body,
        width: '250px',
        background: '#ccc'
    },

    initialize: function(options) {
        this.setOptions(options);
        this.addDemoDiv();
    },

    addDemoDiv: function() {
        var dDiv = new Element('div', {
            'class': 'myClass',
            html: 'Click me!',
            styles: {
                padding: '20px',
                border: '1px solid #999',
                width: this.options.width,
                background: this.options.background
            },
            events: {
                click: this.animate
            }
        });

        dDiv.inject(this.options.container);
    },

    animate: function() {
        alert('Hello world');
    }

});

window.addEvent('domready', function() {

    var item = new F();

});
```

It's supposed to allow the user to specify the container to inject the div into, with the document body being the default. When I do it like above, the code validates OK, but the script fails to add the div - Firebug and Chrome complain about the container being null or undefined.

I have to change `dDiv.inject(this.options.container);` to this

```
if (!this.container) {
    dDiv.inject(document.body);
} else {
    dDiv.inject(this.container);
}
```

to make it work.

Can any wise Mootools ninja tell me why inject works when I pass document.body in directly, but breaks when I try to pass it a reference to document.body supposedly stored in the class's container option? I've tried variations on document.body, like 'document.body' and $$('document.body') and $$(document.body).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that `document.body` is not available when your class code gets interpreted, this usually occurs when your script is placed in the `<head>` tags. Moving your script(s) to the bottom of the document (just before `</body>`) solves a lot and is good practise since your script(s) won't block HTML rendering anymore either.

It's also better to avoid putting a static default DOM references in your class as their availability is always questionable. You can keep `options.container` null and change your method to:

```
... code ...
dDiv.inject( this.options.container || document.body );
... code ...
```

So if `this.options.container` is not set (falsy) it will default to `document.body`, this way you can also keep your script(s) in the `<head>` if you really want to.

Comment: Oh! Cheers BG.. I'd have assumed that `document.body` is only interpreted when the class is instantiated on domready, but this does sound right, thanks for your advice!

Comment: for better readability do `this.element = $(this.options.container) || document.body;` in your initialize, which also gives you the flexibility of passing on an object or an ID string to it.